# SVG coordinates created using Illustrator's Curvature tool

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have upgraded my Illustrator from CS6 to the latest version so now I can use the curvature tool to draw curves. I am exporting them as .svg.
The SVG code output has changed a bit and I'd like to be sure I understand it correctly.
Here is the code:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.28 841.89;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M305,816.89c,-224.62,-2,-344.18,-3.06,-375,-1c,-3.64,0.24,-18.06,1.33,-37,-1c,-19.51,-2.4,-33.83,-7.21,-42,-10
     c,-65.47,-22.37,-105,-55,-105,-55c,-10.1,-8.34,-84.92,-72.03,-99,-178c,-1.04,-7.84,-1.07,-20.99,-2,-47c,-1.48,-41.41,-2.05,-78.59,-2,-88
     c0.17,-32.14,9.57,-109.72,60,-174c71.76,-91.46,187.22,-105.81,229,-111c22.88,-2.84,39.98,-2.96,52,-3c318.56,-1.1,516.18,3.53,625,0
     c23.13,-0.75,54.42,-0.83,117,-1c56.56,-0.15,68.43,0.3,84,3c55.87,9.67,94.93,37.05,113,50c16.45,11.79,105.65,75.73,120,182
     c0.63,4.69,1.09,16.12,2,39c4.34,108.97,-4.33,150.16,-7,162c,-1.75,7.77,-5.96,25.24,-14,47c,-7.51,20.34,-45.7,123.76,-129,165
     c,-18.14,8.98,-37.57,14.59,-39,15c,-32.94,9.38,-59.54,9.09,-69,9C626.34,818.28,465.66,818.32,305,816.89z"/>
    </svg>
```

If I understand things correctly, the first line where d="M... is the definition of my first curve. The first point is the beginning of the curve. The first c character defines the two control points' as well as the end point's relative coordinates (relative to the first point).

But then I have a second c on this line. I think this means that it is now "drawing" the second curve. But where is the start point? It's the 4th one from the line above (with absolute coordinates), right? The 3 points described after this second c are the new 2nd, 3rd and 4th points (in relative coordinates), correct?

It then goes on... until there is a C (capital c) at the end which indicates absolute coordinates. So again, the first point should be the 4th from the line above (with absolute coordinates) and the points after this capital "C" are the 2nd, 3rd and 4th points (in absolute coordinates this time).

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: This is all described in the documentation. [Multiple sets of coordinates may be specified to draw a polybézier. At the end of the command, the new current point becomes the final (x,y) coordinate pair used in the polybézier.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands).

Comment: Thank you. I saw that. I'm trying to export and plot on MatLab the coordinates from the .svg. If the code I write is false, I'm going to be real sad.

Comment: I was able to create a basic code which plots bezier curves based on those 4 points. in just a few minutes. I extracted the data manually of another drawing with only 4 curves and tested the code, curve by curve and my theory was indeed correct.

Comment: There are errors in the path `d` attribute. There is a coma after the c command that shouldn't be there.